# Cordova: multiple gap://ready network calls on ios and android

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I've build application with core cordova and JQuery, JQuery templates.
App is working fine for browser platform, but for android and device platform I got multiple calls to gap://ready.

[image]
Any Idea about this

**ADDED INFORMATION**

On Android its giving dialog as shown in images below (sequentially 1 by 1):

[image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: gap://ready is an iOS thing, you are probably using the iOS cordova.js for all platforms and it's different for each

Comment: @jcesarmobile I'm using default cordova.js for different platforms. I've not changed anything in there.

Comment: Each platform needs a different cordova.js, there is no "default" cordova.js

Comment: @jcesarmobile that's what I mean I've not changed the cordova.js any where.

Comment: but you are opening the iOS index.html on the browser, that is wrong, you have to open iOS index.html inside an iOS cordova app, you can't test iOS files on the browser, you have to add the browser platform for that

Comment: ya I got the problem, It will not run because its checking the files inside the device, but I'm testing the app using cordova server which will not work in case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got answer my self.
I'm testing using cordova server.
In this cases if we've not added device plugin I'll work but once we've added device plugin we can't test ios on cordova server.
We've to deploy in ios device.

Thanks @jcesarmobile for your response.